¿Cómo escanear la estructura de todas las tablas, de todas las bases de datos en un servidor MySQL?
El siguiente código funciona bien para lo que necesito, tiene dos consultas anidadas, creo que sería bueno que fuera una sola, pero de ella requiero 2 resultados no uno, a saber: REF_COL_NAME y REF_NAME.
Pregunta:
¿Hay alguna forma de modificar la consulta para que devuelva los mismos resultados, sin usar consultas anidadas?
SELECT
conf.TABLE_SCHEMA,
conf.TABLE_NAME,
conf.ORDINAL_POSITION,
conf.COLUMN_NAME,
conf.DATA_TYPE,
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(conf.COLUMN_TYPE, conf.DATA_TYPE, ''), '(', ''), ')', '') AS 'DATA_LENGTH',
conf.COLUMN_KEY,
(
    SELECT inncol.REF_COL_NAME
    FROM INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS AS inncol, 
    INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN as inn
    WHERE inncol.ID = inn.ID
    AND inn.FOR_NAME = CONCAT(CONCAT(conf.TABLE_SCHEMA,'/'),conf.TABLE_NAME)
    AND conf.COLUMN_KEY = 'MUL'
) as 'REF_COL_NAME',
(
    SELECT REPLACE(inn2.REF_NAME, CONCAT(conf.TABLE_SCHEMA,'/'), '')
    FROM INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS AS inncol2, 
    INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN as inn2
    WHERE inncol2.ID = inn2.ID
    AND inn2.FOR_NAME = CONCAT(CONCAT(conf.TABLE_SCHEMA,'/'),conf.TABLE_NAME)
    AND conf.COLUMN_KEY = 'MUL'
) as 'REF_NAME'
FROM
information_schema.COLUMNS as conf,
INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS AS inncol,
INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN as inn
WHERE conf.TABLE_SCHEMA != 'information_schema'
AND conf.TABLE_SCHEMA != 'mysql'
AND conf.TABLE_SCHEMA != 'performance_schema'
AND conf.TABLE_SCHEMA != 'phpmyadmin'
AND inncol.ID = inn.ID
ORDER by conf.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND conf.TABLE_NAME
AND conf.ORDINAL_POSITION;


Con consultas anidadas, como les llamas, no se puede, pero si podrías hacerlo con un left join.
